# Get words before and after string with whitespace

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to retrieve 5 words before after a particular word using regex. My code is as follows.

```
$str= '<li>111-37774 Blue</li><li>111-1566 Red</li><li>122-4555 White</li><li>1455-789 Yellow</li></ul>Minimum order applies. This is a string for testing.<p>';
$regexForPattern ='/((?:\w+\W\s*){0,5})minimum\b((?:\W*\w+){0,5})/i';   
preg_match_all ($regexForPattern , trim( preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', $str) ), $patternMatches); 
print_r($patternMatches);
```

I want 5 words before and after the word 'minimum' from `$str`.

Currently I'm getting the output as:

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array ( [0] => 4555 White 1455-789 Yellow Minimum order applies. This is a ) 
            [1] => Array ( [0] => 4555 White 1455-789 Yellow ) 
            [2] => Array ( [0] => order applies. This is a ) 
)
```

I expect the string **122-4555 White 1455-789 Yellow** instead of **4555 White 1455-789 Yellow** in the resultant array. For the words like *1455-789* it is considering *1455* as one word and *789* as another. How can I get only exact words?

Can anyone help me to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably, you want to replace `(?:\w+\W\s*){0,5}` with `(?:\S+\s+){0,5}` and `(?:\W*\w+){0,5}` with `(?:\s+\S+){0,5}`

Comment: you could also push this back to the SQL layer by using SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX - might be simpler for you, see following resource - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471199/get-all-characters-before-space-in-mysql

Comment: BTW, here is a regex fiddle - https://regex101.com/r/NRJCSz/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew..Thanks..Its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w` cannot match `-` between the digits, hence the regex fails to fetch the expected substring from the expected location.

You should replace `(?:\w+\W\s*){0,5}` with `(?:\S+\s+){0,5}` and `(?:\W*\w+){0,5}` with `(?:\s+\S+){0,5}`:

```
'~((?:\S+\s+){0,5})minimum\b((?:\s+\S+){0,5})~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRJCSz/1).

That way, you will match any 0 to 5 space-separated non-whitespace chunks before and after the keyword.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/yNAjvC):

```
$str= '<li>111-37774 Blue</li><li>111-1566 Red</li><li>122-4555 White</li><li>1455-789 Yellow</li></ul>Minimum order applies. This is a string for testing.<p>';
$regexForPattern ='/((?:\S+\s+){0,5})minimum\b((?:\s+\S+){0,5})/i';   
$nstr = trim( preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', $str));
echo $nstr . "\n";
preg_match_all ($regexForPattern , $nstr, $patternMatches); 
print_r($patternMatches);
```