# Get 3 letters from first word and 3 from next word

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m trying to get the first 3 letters from first word and 3 from next word. The names in database are different. If name is James Fiddler i want it to be JAMFID

Tried to use SUBSTRING_INDEX but i cant understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT UPPER(CONCAT(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', 1),3)
,LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', -1),3)));
```

Which gives You

```
UPPER(CONCAT(LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', 1),3)
,LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', -1),3)))
JAMFID
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried the LEFT() function in combination with the LOCATE() function?
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php

In your case, I think it would be (haven't tested this)

```
SELECT LEFT(name, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1), LEFT(name, LOCATE(' ', name))
```

Maybe this article can help you: [Get all characters before space in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471199/get-all-characters-before-space-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first,' ',1),1,3),SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first,' ',-1),1,3) )FROM Test;
```

Try this...

Answer (score 0):

May help full to you:

```
Declare @name varchar(100)='ABCDEFG PQRSTU'
SELECT Left(substring(@name, 1,charindex(' ',@name)),3)+LEFT(substring(@name, charindex(' ',@name)+1,len(@name)-charindex(' ',@name)+1),3)
```